# How do I install react node modules?

Tags: reactjs

How do I install react node modules? I downloaded a react file from GitHub, but there are no node_modules. Now how do I download node_modules from that file.

Comment: You can follow the steps https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html

Comment: npm install or yarn install if there is package.json

Answer (score 2):

Navigate to the project you have downloaded and run this command `npm install` . This will download all the necessary dependencies

Answer (score -2):

Here is a simple solution
import React from "react";
The from "react" should be lower caps
In my case it was upper case and after changing to "react" in lower case the problem resolved.

Comment: This response does not answer the question of how to install node modules.